# Not correct reverse sort in dired mode

Tags: dired, sorting

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.2

Installed packages:
dired+
dired-hacks-utils-20201005.2318
dired-k-20200322.2035
dired-narrow-20181114.1723
dired-quick-sort-20201221.403
dired-recent-20211004.1924
dired-sort-menu+
dired-subtree-20210105.1127

Here content of folder dev/deploy in reverse order by **Name**.

In file manager Nemo:
[image]

Same result in Midnight Commander:
[image]

Nice. It's correct.

But in Emacs (in Dired mode) has different result:
[image]

Why in Emacs reverse order is incorrect?
I reverse sort by press "s"

```
(dired-sort-toggle-or-edit &optional ARG)
```

Comment: You have too much going on that you're not specifying in your vague recipe that describes the problem. Instead of loading several libraries, and and all of which *might* be contributing to the problem, bisect your init file to find the culprit. Then rewrite your question to present a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). What you're doing so far is just loading a giant sack of stuff and then asking others to debug. Narrow the problem - remove everything that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different applications will always sort things differently; there is on one perfect way to do it. In particular, two of the files in your screenshots have precisely the same timestamp. This means that they always tie when compared, and the order they end up in will depend on the details of how the application was written. Some applications will look to other fields, such as the file name, to break the tie, while others will simply let them end up in whatever order they happen to end up in. In an application that uses a stable sort, this might simply be whatever order the operating system happened to list them in the directory entry. In applications using an unstable sort this could be effectively random.

If you don’t like how Emacs has sorted them, then dive into the code yourself and explore. I caution you that you might spend a lifetime just on sorting, and still find that there are more options to consider.

Edit: You’ve edited your question to clarify that you wanted to sort by the file name rather than the date. But that’s not what `s` does! `s` toggles between sorting the directory by name and by date. Since it started out sorted by name, it toggled it to sort by date instead.

However, if you give it a prefix argument (by typing `C-u s`), then it will prompt you to type in the flags you would like to give to ls. Add an `r` to it so that it becomes `-alr` and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your Dired screenshot tells you, in the mode-line, that it's sorted by ***DATE***, not by name.

Looks like the problem is pilot error.  (A guess is that you tried to use `s` to reverse the sort-by-name order.  `s` instead toggles between sort-by-name and sort-by-time.)

If you want to *reverse* the current sort, add `r` as one of your listing switches (e.g. `dired-listing-switches` or Dired with a prefix arg).

---

See my comment to your question. Don't just load a zillion packages, any or all of which *might be* contributing to your problem somehow, and ask people to debug.

Instead, narrow your presentation of the problem by bisecting your init file to find any culprit(s), and then provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`, to reproduce the problem.  This is the right thing to do, when debugging on your own. And it's the right thing to do, especially, when asking for help.

Had you done that, I expect that, in trying to provide a careful recipe, you would have discovered that you were in fact asking Emacs to sort by **date**, not by file name.

Comment: Also can use package "dired-quick-sort". It's very simple to use.